# The state of margin notes

Tags: marginpar, marginnote

marginpar seems to be one of the more pressing problems with LaTeX for quite a few authors who would like to become LaTeX users or extend their usage of LaTeX. Is my impression correct that the support for flexible margin notes (especially next to floats) is pretty limited? This bugged me for quite some time until I pretty much switched to LaTeX for almost all writing and let LaTeX (package authors) dictate what my documents could or could not (with reasonable efforts [and for me that can be a few dozends of hours to unlock a structure I miss plus I am a computer scientist]) contain as structural elements.

To me having not solved this one today presents itself as a problem for the workflow mainly as TODO notes used to be one of the more important kind of information to me, that would end up at the margins. The other thing still bugging me regularly is including notes to stuff that fills multiple pages in tables (have been using longtable since 2005 with acceptable results).

Any hints for stuff I am missing?

Comment: There is no point to debate if  \marginpar is  good or  bad, but specific problems using it. There are packages to help  with margins notes as `todonotes`. You should visit https://www.ctan.org/topic/notes.

Comment: What is your problem with margin notes? The `memoir` class provides a variety of these: `\marginpar` the regular macro; `sidenote` non floating `\marginpar`; `\sidebar` text starts near the top of the page and can continue over multiple pages; `\sidefootnote` footnotes in the margin.

Comment: @PeterWilson: it does not work from float environments which is a huge problem considering multiple kinds of tables, figures and more

Comment: @ErikItter Please provide an MWE that shows your problem. I have a feeling that you are trying to put a `\marginpar` inside a float environment. A `\marginpar` is a kind of float and as far as I am aware you can't embed a float within another float --- try putting a table inside a figure.

Comment: well, the environment seems to be e.g. every simple text paragraph in twosided documents that flows over a pagebreak (not the command, but simply to the next page in normal standard text). If the marginpar content does not fit onto the page the paragraph starts at the marginpar will appear on the second page (fine) on the wrong side (not fine at all).

Maybe I'll give memoir a try for my next book but changing the document class isn't really a solution for a concrete problem.